# Change NavigationView menu group divider color programatically in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview

[image]

In my project i have to change the color of navigation view group divider.So I should change in activity file.We can  change color statically like above picture.I have given green color in styles but i need divider should be in many colors.Any help very appreciable :)

Comment: any picture of your expected output?

Comment: @Charuක i have given green color in style but i need to apply color dynamicllay.thanks in advance

Comment: both at once right?

Comment: @Charuක based on user choice i need to change the divider color.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **custom layout** for your drawer and achieve that keeping in mind is that the `NavigationDrawer` can have only two children. Then you can add your own divider there and change color as you need.

Example: customize as you wish

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- YOUR DRAWER -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_view_lin"
    android:layout_width="200"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

    <!-- Your Other Views -->
    <ListView  // or any view depending on your requirement
        android:id="@+id/ListView_one"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

     <!-- Your Devider View-->
     <!-- Your Other Views -->
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

To get a quick idea if I divide drawer_view_lin to 5 parts(designing is up to you),like this you can add a separators

[image]

Comment: thank you so much but i am not undrstanding it.can i add navigation iew to it?

Comment: @Narender Reddy  Its a custom layout.You can keep the DrawerLayout and set a custom view inside it  thats what i did.So you can add anything as you want.

Comment: You have your **activity_main.xml** there you can setup this.The views that you are going to add is up to you and this is a customization so boundaries but make sure you remove `navigationView` initialization part default generated

Comment: @Narender Reddy add in image to get the idea make sure you design it as the way it looks like the default one so you can even change the color of separate divider cuz they all have different ids

Comment: @@Narender Reddy did you able to make it ?

Answer (score -1):

following code for Navigation view in Drawer Layout.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#f2f2f2"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_daum_map_view_main"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationItemTheme"/>
```

use following style theme in values/styles.xml.

```
<style name="NavigationItemTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">13sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/BlackColor</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">46dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Add divider background color programmatically using following code in java class.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);//your color
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);//your menu layout
```

Comment: Thanks for replay.I want change only divider color not background i am using another background color.